# Can I use my custom ERC-20 with my smart contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

So I have a contract that allows you to exchange ETH for my custom ERC20 token. I am wanting to use that custom ERC20 token now with other smart contracts. Is there a certain way I have to specify the custom token vs ETH?

example:

pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

/*
* ---How to use:
*  1. Send HYPER Tokens to the smart contract address in any amount.
*  2. Claim your profit by sending 0 HYPER transaction (1 time per hour)
*  3. If you do not withdraw and earn more than 200%, you can withdraw only one time over the 200% allowance
*/
contract HyperLENDtest {

```
using SafeMath for uint;
mapping(address => uint) public balance;
mapping(address => uint) public time;
mapping(address => uint) public percentWithdraw;
mapping(address => uint) public allPercentWithdraw;
```

function percentRate() public view returns(uint) {
        uint contractBalance = address(this).balance;

```
    if (contractBalance < 100 ether) {
        return (20);
    }
    if (contractBalance >= 500 ether && contractBalance < 1000 ether) {
        return (40);
    }
    if (contractBalance >= 1000 ether && contractBalance < 2000 ether) {
        return (60);
    }
    if (contractBalance >= 2000 ether) {
        return (80);
    }
```

Instead of returning ETH I want to use my custom ERC20 token to users to send to the contract and get in return % of the ERC20 token back.

Answer (score 1):

Your contract is just another address so yes, you can send tokens to your contract. But you cannot send them the same way you send ether, that is using a payable function. You have to transfer the tokens to the contract's address using the transfer method of you ERC-20 token. And to send tokens from the contract to someone else you have to call transfer from inside your contract unless you do something like provide a lot of allowance for your account, but I wouldn't suggest this. How exactly you can call methods from your ERC-20 from inside your other contract is explained in [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46318/how-can-i-transfer-erc20-tokens-from-a-contract-to-an-user-account) post.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, so I am aware of the transfer function but what I am trying to achieve is using my contract as it exists and using my custom ERC20 token vs ETH. So for example in this game, a user sends X eth to the contract and in return gets a % back each day. But instead of ETH in return I want to provide them my custom ERC20 token and not ETH.

Comment: It certainly is possible, but you will need to provide them of a way to buy and send your ERC-20 token. I think the simplest way would using metamask unless you want to create an interface yourself. So if you use metamask you can have them buy tokens buy sending ether to your ERC-20 contract, which is the standard way to do it. After they have some tokens they need to add this token to their metamask account so that they can transfer tokens using metamask. This guide describes how to add custom ERC-20 tokens to metamask: http://luvcrypto.com/add-send-tokens-metamask/

Comment: And you also need to notify your other contract about the token transfer. I know it is a little more complicated than using ether.

Comment: thats where I am running into the issue, I am not sure how to differentiate ETH vs the custom token in the contract. I have a UI currently built. But when I use the smart contract and try to replace ETHER value with my token it throws errors. I do understand up to adding the token to metamask and all that. Its really how to get the contract to recognize its an ERC20 token and not ETH ( code noted in original post above)

Comment: Ether and tokens are sent in different ways. A transaction may contain ether, but a transaction cannot contain tokens. The transaction will tell the contract to transfer tokens. So the contract can know if it is ERC-20 or Ether based on the function that is executed. When you "send" ERC-20 tokens it is actually just tha balances that change in the ERC-20 contract, you don't really send something with the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a e-commerce business for example. So the way I did it was:

1. The user would buy tokens buy sending Ether to your ERC-20 contract. The rate between Ether and your token is totally up to you as it is relative to the business and not Ether itself. 
   In this business case let's say we give the 100 tokens for each Ether. The user passes 2 Ether to the contract and 200 of your business tokens are then put into your contract's 
   `mapping(address => uint) accounts`.
   Given this the following code would give you 200:
   `accounts[customer_address] //(returns 200)`
2. Then you would have another contract, let's say to purchase a given item. You just have to call this smart contract purchase function from that address. Then this function is responsible to call your ERC-20 contract to check if the user has enough funds considering his/her address. If so, then your contract would transfer the given number of tokens to your ERC-20 contract to the available tokens or another wallet you'd like it to, basically transferring the user (address) tokens to another address you decide to.

This way your user is using your tokens which have been previously bought and not even thinking about Ether.
Please remember that the GAS fee has to be paid. So either you pay for it or your customers will (include it on the price of the item or so).

Hope this helps someone with the same question :)